# how to post value in database in arry form

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm creating an application to register route of a bus, giving it route name once and creating a text box and a select box dynamically for the user to create a bus stop on that route as much as he want.
This is my CodeIgniter's view: a script to create textboxes and select box dynamically in a form div.

I want to post its entered data in my data base having fields as follow:

```
route_number     stop_name  am_pm  timing
```

Can you please help me with CodeIgniter models controller function? The view is the following:

```
<form method='post' action='<?php echo site_url('a3_bus_system/output')?>'>
<div class="_25">
<strong>Route Name/Number</strong>
     <br/>
<input type="text" name=""></input>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;<p>&nbsp;</p></p>
<p>&nbsp;<p>&nbsp;</p></p>
<div id="div">
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p><div class="_25">
<p><input type="button" name="button" class="button red" id="button" value="Add"  onclick="generateRow() "/></a></p>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
 <input type="submit"  class="button blue" id="button" value="Register" />
/form>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear height-fix"></div>
</div></div> <!--! end of #main-content -->
</div> <!--! end of #main -->
<script>
var counter=1;
  function generateRow() {
var count="<font color='red'>"+counter+"</font>";
var temp ="<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox' name='stop"+counter+"' placeholder='Stop Name'></input></div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class='_25'><input type='textbox' id='textbox' name='timing"+counter+"' placeholder='Timing'></input></div>&nbsp;<div class='_25'><select id='ampm"+counter+"' name='ampm"+counter+"'><option>a.m</option><option>p.m</option></select>  </div>";
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.innerHTML = temp + count;
var yourDiv = document.getElementById('div');
yourDiv.appendChild(newdiv);
counter++;
}
</script>
```

Comment: So that's why the buses run late....

Comment: yaaa now can u plz make it run on time?

Comment: where is the question? I mean the problem?

Comment: I want to post its entered data in my data base having fields as follow:

route_number     stop_name  am_pm  timing 

Can you please help me with CodeIgniter models controller function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to submit the form to the same PHP file, by passing the `counter` parameter we know how many set of data has been submitted then we can insert the data to your database. after submitting the form the following php code will insert the data to your database:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["counter"]) && !empty($_POST["route"])){
    $counter = $_POST["counter"];
    $route   = $_POST["route"];
    $pdo     = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "database");
    $stmt    = "INSERT INTO table_name(route_number, stop_name, am_pm, timing) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $insert  = $pdo->prepare($stmt);

    for($i = 1; $i <= $counter; $i++)
    {
        $stop   = $_POST["stop" . $i];
        $timing = $_POST["timing" . $i];
        $ampm   = $_POST["ampm" . $i];
        $insert->bind_param("isss", $route, $stop, $ampm, $timing);
        $insert->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $pdo->close();
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Buss Routes</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 1;

    function generateRow() {
        var count = "<p align='center' ><font color='red'>" + counter + "</font></p></div>";
        var temp = "<div id='container" + counter + "'  class='_25' >"
            + "<input type='text' name='stop" + counter + "' placeholder='Stop Name' />"
            + "<input type='text' name='timing" + counter + "' placeholder='Timing' />"
            + "<select name='ampm" + counter + "'><option>a.m</option><option>p.m</option></select>"
            + "<input type='button' onClick='Javascript:this.parentNode.remove(); counter--;' value='Remove' />";
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = temp + count;
        document.getElementById('div').appendChild(newdiv);
        document.getElementById('counter').value = counter;
        counter++;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
    <div class="_25">
        <p align="center"><strong>Route Name/Number</strong></p>
        <input type="text" name="route" placeholder="Route Number" />
    </div>
    <div id="div"></div>
    <div class="_25">
        <input type="button" class="button red" value="Add" onclick="generateRow()" />
        <input type="hidden" name="counter" id="counter" />
        <input type="submit" class="button blue" value="Register" />
    </div>
    </form>
<div class="clear height-fix" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a demo shows how the javascript code work: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/EJ6xN/)

Replace `host`, `database`, `username`, `password` with your server's details and `table_name` with the table name that contain the data.

---

For CodeIgniter try this instead of the above php code (not tested, i never used CodeIgniter before but by checking the documentation on ellislab website this should work):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["counter"]) && !empty($_POST["route"])){
    $counter = $_POST["counter"];
    $route   = $_POST["route"];
    $this->load->database();

    for($i = 1; $i <= $counter; $i++)
    {
        $data = (
            'route_number' => $route,
            'stop_name'    => $_POST["stop" . $i],
            'am_pm'        => $_POST["ampm" . $i],
            'timing'       => $_POST["timing" . $i]
        );
        $this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
    }
}
?>
```